# how to use EntityFramework.patterns with ninject in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ninject

I'm trying to use EntityFramework.Patterns package from nuget , but i'm stuck,here is my

question : how to use ninject to inject productRepo and unitOfWork within a mvc Controller ?

here is the tutorial link : http://efpatterns.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pattern%20%3a%20Use%20Repository%20and%20UOF

```
DbContextAdapter adapter = new DbContextAdapter(ctx);
IRepository<Product> productRepo = new Repository<Product>(adp);
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(adp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor taking them as arguments to the Controller. Search for constructor injection for more details.

Answer (score 0):

- Download Ninject.MVC3 package from nuget.
- Remove the "ninject web common" piece from your AppStart folder
- Open your global.asax and change your code to look like to following

```
namespace OnBoardingMVC
{
    public class MvcApplication : Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            NinjectConfig.RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }    
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create a new NinjectConfig.cs file in your App_Start folder and add the following code to your class:

```
namespace OnBoardingMVC
{
    public class NinjectConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            // e.g. kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IEmployeeUow))
                  .To(typeof(EmployeeUow))
                  .WithConstructorArgument("adapter", <Add new AdapterVariable here>)
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then create an `EmployeeUow` class that inherits from the `UnitOfWork` class and also create a `IEmployeeUow` that inherits from the `IUnitOfWork` and the context adapter would be a parameter for the constructor and that construtor would also pass the adapter to the base constructor of the `UnitOfWork` class.